# block all non-vpn traffic

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, iptables, vpn

Disclaimer: I have no experience with Linux or networking whatsoever.

I want to block all non-vpn traffic on my Fedora 25 PC. That means, only my VPN provider's IPs should ever be allowed for any internet traffic. I also want to use only their DNS server.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

'I have no experience with Linux'

*runs Fedora*

```
sudo dnf install ufw
sudo ufw default deny incoming
sudo ufw default deny outgoing
sudo ufw allow out to [VPN server IP] port 443 proto udp
sudo ufw allow out to [VPN provider's DNS IP] port 53
sudo ufw allow out on tun0 from any to any
sudo ufw enable
```

Comment: DNS server, per question, too?

Comment: These commands have a rather large security/privacy problem: They allow dns to occur outside of the VPN. The question asker almost certainly wants the DNS *inside* the VPN. To fix it, remove the line 'sudo ufw allow out to [VPN provider's DNS IP] port 53'. You see, if the DNS was occurring over the VPN tun0 there's no need to have an extra ufw rule about it.